# Как сравнить символы из имени человека со списком жанров литературы и порекомендовать ему исходя из букв его имени?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Всем привет
Маленькая тест-программа для меня.
Интересует как сравнить символы с именем.
Если в имени присутствует буква Ф то программа порекомендует жанр : "Фантастика" и т.д.

Учу Питон 3 день: вот что я пытался написать
Всем буду благодарен за ответы.

```
import time

print ( ' Привет. Меня зовут Книжок. ' )
#time.sleep(1)

print ( ' Я могу помочь тебе выбрать жанр литературы который тебе будет 
интересен к прочтению исходя из твоего имени и возраста ' )
#time.sleep(1)

name = input( ' Сперва скажи как тебя зовут ?: ' )
#time.sleep(1)

age = input ( 'Привет ' + name + ' . Сколько тебе лет ? ' )
#time.sleep(1)

print( ' Хорошо ' + name + '.' )
print ('Пару мгновений магии :3')
print ('...')
#time.sleep(1)
print ('...')
#time.sleep(1)
print ('...')
#time.sleep(1)

list(name)

# ДЕМО-ПРИМЕРЫ
if name == 'А' :
    print ( ' Алегория ' )
elif name == 'р' :
    print ('Бархатнина')
elif name == 'и' :
    print ('Фниошик')
```

Пытаюсь сделать для своей девушки, её тоже интересует программирование и хочу показать что программирование это не сложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Если в ... присутствует"* - конкретно такие проверки можно произвести с помощью оператора `in`

Вот небольшой пример:

```py
name = input()

name = name.lower()
if 'д' in name:
    print('Детективы')
elif 'ф' in name:
    print('Фантастика')
elif 'р' in name:
    print('Романтика')
```

Если будет введено имя `Дмитрий`, то программа напечатает `Детективы`.
А Екатерине код порекомендует романтику.

***P. S.:*** Также я решил перед проверкой приводить имя к нижнему регистру, так как это регистрозависимо. Буквы `Д` и `д` *- разные буквы.*

Comment: Спасибо большое))  Маленькое дополнение.
Как можно например сделать  если возраст пользователя больше 15 то брать рекомендации из определенного списка для него.
Если например больше 18 то можно и литературу более глубокую и смысловую . 
Хотелось бы ещё сделать как то так. Пользователь ввёл своё имя. Сделать описание жанра почему именно он подходит, и почему  ему  может нравится (хотя бы полуправдивые предсказывания)
Дальше порекомендовать ему список книг из этого жанра , наиболее популярные с выводом обложки и ссылкой(например).

Comment: @nepy Слишком много вопросов :) Для проверки возраста, всё та же конструкция `if`. С жанрами сложнее. Конечно, можно продолжить конструкциями `if-elif-else`, но я бы так делать не стал. Думаю, для этого подойдут списки (`list`) и цикл `for`. Для хранения описания жанра и т. п. подойдёт словарь (`dict`). Изучите их и попробуйте переписать код с ними. Если что-то конкретно будет непонятно, то с радостью помогу.